# Intent error while using startWakefulService

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use `startWakefulService(context, intent)`

But after encoutering some issues I debugged my app and found that the intent being passed on to the method is false, it uses

`Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=com.myApp.beta cmp=com.myApp.beta/fonctionnalite.Actualites.GcmReceiver (has extras) }`

Instead of

`Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=fonctionnalite.Actualites cmp=fonctionnalite.Actualites.GcmReceiver (has extras) }`

So basically I'm trying to call the class called `GcmReceiver` which is in the package `fonctionnalite.Actualites`. I tried using a different component and intent but it still didn't work, would anyone know how I can solve this problem ?

Thanks !

Here is the code for the class using startWakefulService

```
public class GcmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmMessageHandler.class.getName());

    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. In this case, it would include the code where you are creating the `Intent` and calling `startWakefulService()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the necessary code

Comment: Apparently, `context.getPackageName()` is returning `com.myApp.beta`. What is the `applicationId` of your app?

Comment: @CommonsWare my application Id is `com.myApp.beta`

Comment: "I'm trying to call the class called GcmReceiver which is in the package fonctionnalite.Actualites" -- are you saying that `GcmReceiver` is a `Service` in a separate app? That's not going to work with `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`. If `GcmReceiver` is in your app, then the Java package of that class does not matter for the `pkg` part of the `ComponentName`. The component name is made up of the application ID of the app with the component plus the fully-qualified class name of the component itself.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the explanation ! The class `GcmReceiver`is indeed in the same app. So what I did was replace the component definition with the following `ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.myApp.beta", "fonctionnalite.Actualites.GcmMessageHandler");` The first part of the constructor is the appId, the second part is the fully qualified name of my class, it should've worked but still it doesn't. I'll try figuring it out, thanks for your help !